# Understanding Indexes and Missing Index Recommendations in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

**UNDERSTANDING INDEXES & MISSING INDEX RECOMMENDATIONS**

I'm trying to gain a better understanding of indexes. I have a lot of reading to do, and have found a number of valuable resources from other SO posts, some of which I've read, others I still need to read. In the meantime, I'm trying to get better performance out of my database.

I've learned that a covering index is going to be better performing than indexes on individual columns, so I decided to start by deleting my individual indexes and letting the proposed query execution plan recommend indexes.

**SSMS INDEX RECOMMENDATION**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_my_index_name
ON [dbo].[my_table] ([field_a],[field_b])
INCLUDE (
   [field_1]
  ,[field_2]
  ,[field_3]
  ,[field_4]
  ,[field_5]
  ,[field_6]
)
```

**TABLE DETAILS**

fields 1-6 are the columns I commonly use to join the 2 tables I'm using.  fields a & b are found in the where clause of a few time consuming queries I run.

I understand using fields 1-6 because for the most part they all contain many different values, but `field a` has only about 75 distinct values, and `field b` only has 3 distinct values. This is in a table with 70MM records in it.

Note that this is a heap. All of the records on this table come from another table that has a primary key, so that unique value comes with it, but it's not set up as a key or a unique index on this table. SSMS didn't recommend including that column in this index. Wondering how I should handle the unique value coming into this table? A clustered, unique index I'm guessing?

**MY QUESTIONS**

1. I want to understand the logic behind this index recommendation. Given the information regarding the similar values in columns a & b, why was this recommended?
2. I want to understand the difference between the `ON` columns and the `INCLUDE` columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd ask is whether there is a good reason for a table of that size doesn't have a clustered index? A clustered key doesn't even have to be unique (SQL Server will add a 'uniquifier' to it if not, although it's usually best to use an IDENTITY column).

To answer your two questions:

1) The index recommendation is related to the query you are running. As a rule of thumb, the suggested columns will match the columns the query optimiser is using to probe into the table, so if you have a query like:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM   table1
WHERE  field4 = 1 AND field5 = 'bob'
```

The suggested index is likely to be on the `field4` and `field5` columns, and in order of selectivity (i.e. the column with the most variation in values first). It may include other columns (for instance `field1, field2, field3`) because then the query optimiser will only have to visit the index to get that data, and not visit the data page.

Note also that sometimes the suggested index is not always the one you might choose yourself. If joining several tables, the query optimiser will choose the execution plan that it thinks best suits the data, based on available indexes and statistics. It might loop over one table and probe into another, when the best possible plan might do it the other way around. You have to inspect the actual query execution plan to see what is going on.

If you know your query is selective enough to drill down to a small range of records (for instance has a where clause like `WHERE table1.field1 = 1 AND table1.field2 = 'abc' AND table1.field3 = '2015-07-01' ...`), you can add an index that covers all the referenced columns. This might influence the query optimiser to scan this index to get a small number of rows to join to another table, rather than performing scans.

As a rule of thumb, a good place to start when examining the execution plans is trying to eliminate scans, where the server will be reading a large range of rows, and provide indexes that narrow down the amount of data that has to be processed.

2) I think others have probably explained this well enough by now - the included columns are there so that when the index is read, the server doesn't then have to read the data page to get those values; they are stored on the index as well.

The initial response a lot of people may have when they read about such 'covering indexes' is "why don't I add a whole bunch of indexes that do this", or "why don't I add an index that covers all the columns".

In some situations (usually small tables with narrow columns, such as many-to-many joining tables), this is useful. However, with each index you add comes some costs:

Firstly, every time you update or insert a value into your table, the index has to be updated. This means you will have to contend with locking, lock escalation issues (possibly deadlocking), page splits, and the associated fragmentation. There are various ways to mitigate these issues, such as using an appropriate fill-factor to allow more values to be inserted into an index page without having to split it.

Secondly, indexes take up space. At the very least, an index is going to contain the key values you use and either the RID (in a heap) or clustering key (in a table with a clustered index). Covering indexes also contain a copy of the included columns. If these are large columns (such as big varchars) then the index can be quite large and it is not unheard of for a tables indexes to add up to be bigger than the table itself. Note that there are also limits on the size of an index, both in terms of columns, and total size. Because the clustering key is always included in non-clustered indexes on a table with a clustered index (the clustered index is on the data page itself), this means that a smaller clustered key is better. Whilst you can use a composite index, this is likely to be several bytes wide, and whilst you can use a non-unique key, SQL Server will add that uniquifier to it, which is another 4 bytes. Best practice is to use an identify column (int, or bigint if you envisage ever having more than 2 billion rows in the table). Identities also always increment, so you won't get page splits in your data pages when inserting a new record, as it will always go on the end of the table.

so the tl;dr; is:

The suggested indexes can be useful, but often don't give the best index. if you know the structure of your data and how it will be queried, you can construct indexes that contain the commonly use probing keys.

Always order the columns in your index in the order of *selectivity* (i.e. the column with the most values first). This might seem counter-intuitive, but it allows SQL Server to find the data you want faster, with fewer reads.

Included columns are useful, but only usually when they are small columns (e.g. integers). If your query needs six columns from a table and the index covers only five of them, SQL Server will still have to visit the data page, so in this case you're better off without the included columns because they just take up space and have a maintenance cost.

Answer (score 3):

The ON columns in the index can be used for searching the rows. Those fields are included in the index tree. Once the rows are found, if any additional columns are needed, for example fields in select part or joins, they have to be fetched from the table. This is called a `key lookup` in the execution plan.

If the index has multiple columns, and not all columns are specified in the where clause, the columns can be used from first onwards as long as the fields are given. For example index has fields A, B, C, D and where clause has fields A, B and D, then only A and B can be used to fetch the data.

If the table has a clustered index, the values of the keys in the clustered index are stored in the other indexes and are used to find the row from the table itself. If there is no clustered index, RID (Row ID) is used in similar way to locate the rows from the table.

The include columns in index are additional columns and their data is stored at the leaf level of the non-clustered index. This way SQL Server can read the data directly from there and skip the whole part of reading the table. This is called a `covering index`.

Answer (score 2):

An included index (or covered index) allows SQL Server to find all the information in needs to satisfy the query in the index itself without having to go back to the actual data pages to get the information requested. Its a copy of the data but the columns in the included part are not used to search - just to return data. Your tables should always (except in very, very special conditions such as when you are doing very large amount of inserts) have a clustered index on it.

The reason an index is used is to reduce the number of scans where SQL Server has to read the entire table to return data. By using an index SQL Server can seek and read only the pages it needs to return the rows you requested. If a column has a limited number of values SQL Server may decide to ignore the index and do a scan. You have to look at the resulting query plan to see if SQL Server uses the index. If SQL Server suggests an index it usually means that the SQL Server engine would use the index. But every index has a cost - it needs to be maintained so don't create too many indexes.

Answer (score 2):

**I want to understand the logic behind this index recommendation. Given the information regarding the similar values in fields a & b, why was this recommended?**

**tl;dr** It all depends on how you are querying the data.

This is a hard question to answer because it depends on how often you query the table, what types of queries, server load, and a bunch of other things.

For example, if you are using fields 1-6 in many queries which run with 'simple plans' then SQL Server wouldn't consider them good canadites for indexing. a 'Simple Plan' or a 'Trivial Plan' is a plan that SQL SERVER gives to any query that it deems not complicated enough to generate a full plan.

The long running queries would be 'fully explored' by SQL SERVER. There histographics would be calculated and stored. This would alert SQL SERVER that existing indexes are not enough. A 'Fully explored' plan is one that SQL SERVER has expanded and generated a non-simple query plan for.

**I want to understand the difference between the ON columns and the INCLUDE columns?**

Difference between On and Include is.

The **On** statement will include that column in the index. Meaning that column is part of the index when stored.

So Indexes work like this. The Index of a table forms a B-Tree. The nodes in the B-Tree contain the clustering-index value, and a ROWID to the rest of the values. If you search the B-Tree for a value that isn't part of the clustering Index, it will first find the clustering Index then it will have a memory address for the rest of the data. It will then Do a second lookup to that memory address for other values.

The **INCLUDE** clause adds the data at the lowest/leaf level, rather than in the index tree. This makes the index smaller because it's not part of the tree

Comment: Indexes doesn't have a memory address to the rest of the data (it might not even exist in the memory). It has the values of the clustering key and it uses those to find the row from the clustered index

Comment: @JamesZ. Good point, i replaced the memory address with ROWID. My understanding is ROWID is the same as a memory address. How are they different?

Comment: Oh yes in case of heaps it's of course RID, and BOL says "row identifier (RID) consisting of the file number, data page number, and slot on the page" --and I assume there  is some kind of mapping between that and address in buffer pool, which is the reason why RID lookup is faster than key lookup.